# Want to get repeated data in a single row

Tags: mysql

I want to get repeated rows in a single row,below is my table

monthly_attendance

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT distinct a.* 
FROM monthly_attendance a 
WHERE a.month = 9
    AND a.year = 2018 
    AND a.batch in (5) 
    AND a.student_id=257
```

But shows in multiple rows, below is my result:

[image]

Comment: how do you want to aggregate the rows?

Comment: incrementing values in column names are suspect and a very very good candidate for normalisation..

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a (fake)  aggregation function for reduce the rows

```
select student_id
    , batch
    , roll_no
    , month
    , year
    , min(a1)
    , min(a2)
    , min(a3)
    , min(a4)
    , min(a5)
    , min(a6)       
    , min(a7)
    , min(a8)
    , min(a9)
    , min(a10)
    , min(a11)
    , min(a12)      
    , min(a13)
    , min(a14)
    , min(a15)
    , min(a16)
    , min(a17)
    , min(a18)      
    , min(a19)  
from monthly_attendance a 
WHERE a.month = 9 
    AND a.year = 2018 
        AND a.batch in (5) 
            and a.student_id=257
GROUP BY student_id
    , batch
    , roll_no
    , month
    , year
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that a normalised data set *might* look this - although there may of course be yet further opportunities for normalisation...

```
student_id batch roll_no ym         a
       257    27    2601 2018-09-00  4 
       257    27    2601 2018-09-00  6
       257    27    2601 2018-09-00  8 
       257     1    2601 2018-09-00 11
       257     5    2601 2018-09-00 12
       257     5    2601 2018-09-00 14 
       257     5    2601 2018-09-00 17
       257     5    2601 2018-09-00 19
```

Comment: @dipti you need to add a other column where you can store the column order like so `student_id batch roll_no ym a position`, `257    27    2601 2018-09-00  4  1` and `257    27    2601 2018-09-00  6 2` then the normalisation model matches your data model if the position is important

Comment: Why not what if he only wanted to have the `a4` (position 4) data within a batch or batches?  But still it is  dependent on his data model and or requirements if he needs it or not.

Comment: "My data model already accounts for that" i geuss i need coffee then because i don't see positions within a batch.. What is a3 (position/column 3) in batch 27? 8?... There isn't a identifiable order in this data..